# In ADF, PDF download for pivot table

Tags: pivot-table, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

In ADF, When clicking one button on JSF page. I need pdf download for pivot table in jsf page?

I can Download normal table, but i need pivot table PDF download?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using Jasper iReport (cross table). You can download PDF pivot table.

References: http://sameh-nassar.blogspot.in/2012/12/using-jasper-report-in-adf-application.html

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know ADF default tool 'export collection listener' can only export to Excel:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/web.1111/b31973/dv_crosstab.htm#ADFUI11478

To import to PDF you should use any Java-to-PDF library and fill the data programmatically, or try to access data right from component, which is not a good practice.